# Randomly concat data frames by row

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

How can I randomly merge, join or concat pandas data frames by row? Suppose I have four data frames something like this (with a lot more rows):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["1_1", "1_1"], 'col2':["1_2", "1_2"], 'col3':["1_3", "1_3"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["2_1", "2_1"], 'col2':["2_2", "2_2"], 'col3':["2_3", "2_3"]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["3_1", "3_1"], 'col2':["3_2", "3_2"], 'col3':["3_3", "3_3"]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["4_1", "4_1"], 'col2':["4_2", "4_2"], 'col3':["4_3", "4_3"]})
```

How can I join these four data frames randomly output something like this (they are randomly merged row for row):

```
  col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3
0  1_1  1_2  1_3  4_1  4_2  4_3  2_1  2_2  2_3  3_1  3_2  3_3
1  2_1  2_2  2_3  1_1  1_2  1_3  3_1  3_2  3_3  4_1  4_2  4_3
```

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
my_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
my_list = random.sample(my_list, len(my_list))
df = pd.DataFrame({'empty' : []})

for row in df:
    new_df = pd.concat(my_list, axis=1)

print new_df
```

Above `for` statement will not work for more than the first row, every row after (I have more) will just be the same, i.e it will only shuffle once:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3
0  4_1  4_2  4_3  1_1  1_2  1_3  2_1  2_2  2_3  3_1  3_2  3_3
1  4_1  4_2  4_3  1_1  1_2  1_3  2_1  2_2  2_3  3_1  3_2  3_3
```

Comment: so you don't care of consistency of columns?

Comment: @MaxU No, don't really care what the columns are named, could be 1,2,3,...,n or something

Comment: i'm asking about values inside one column... in your desired DF first `col1` has a mixture of values from different columns - is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the important thing is that the all 1_i comes together in a row, all 2_i comes together in a row, etc, but in a random order in the row. So this will mixture the values like you said and it is intended, thanks for clearing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** a much better solution from @Divakar:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["1_1", "1_1"], 'col2':["1_2", "1_2"], 'col3':["1_3", "1_3"], 'col4':["1_4", "1_4"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["2_1", "2_1"], 'col2':["2_2", "2_2"], 'col3':["2_3", "2_3"], 'col4':["2_4", "2_4"]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["3_1", "3_1"], 'col2':["3_2", "3_2"], 'col3':["3_3", "3_3"], 'col4':["3_4", "3_4"]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':["4_1", "4_1"], 'col2':["4_2", "4_2"], 'col3':["4_3", "4_3"], 'col4':["4_4", "4_4"]})

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
n = len(dfs)
nrows = dfs[0].shape[0]
ncols = dfs[0].shape[1]
A = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).values.reshape(nrows,-1,ncols)
sidx = np.random.rand(nrows,n).argsort(1)
out_arr = A[np.arange(nrows)[:,None],sidx,:].reshape(nrows,-1)
df = pd.DataFrame(out_arr)
```

Output:

```
In [203]: df
Out[203]:
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14   15
0  3_1  3_2  3_3  3_4  1_1  1_2  1_3  1_4  4_1  4_2  4_3  4_4  2_1  2_2  2_3  2_4
1  4_1  4_2  4_3  4_4  2_1  2_2  2_3  2_4  3_1  3_2  3_3  3_4  1_1  1_2  1_3  1_4
```

Explanation: (c) Divakar

**NumPy based solution**

Let's have a NumPy based vectorized solution and hopefully a fast one!

1) Let's reshape an array of concatenated values into a `3D` array "cutting" each row into groups of `ncols` corresponding to the # of columns in each of the input dataframes -

```
A = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).values.reshape(nrows,-1,ncols)
```

2) Next up, we trick `np.aragsort` to give us random unique indices ranging from 0 to `N-1`, where N is the number of input dataframes -

```
sidx = np.random.rand(nrows,n).argsort(1)
```

3) Final trick is NumPy's fancy indexing together with some broadcasting to index into `A` with `sidx` to give us the output array -

```
out_arr = A[np.arange(nrows)[:,None],sidx,:].reshape(nrows,-1)
```

4) If needed, convert to dataframe -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(out_arr)
```

**OLD answer:**

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
n = len(dfs)
ncols = dfs[0].shape[1]
v = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).values
a = np.arange(n * ncols).reshape(n, df1.shape[1])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([v[i, a[random.sample(range(n), n)].reshape(n * ncols,)] for i in dfs[0].index]))
```

Output

```
In [150]: df
Out[150]:
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11
0  1_1  1_2  1_3  3_1  3_2  3_3  4_1  4_2  4_3  2_1  2_2  2_3
1  2_1  2_2  2_3  1_1  1_2  1_3  3_1  3_2  3_3  4_1  4_2  4_3
```

Explanation:

```
In [151]: v
Out[151]:
array([['1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '3_1', '3_2', '3_3', '4_1', '4_2', '4_3'],
       ['1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '3_1', '3_2', '3_3', '4_1', '4_2', '4_3']], dtype=object)

In [152]: a
Out[152]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Comment: Nice, however, this will only work if I have two rows, lets say if I have 1000 rows and every df contains of lets say 30 columns? `a` must then be something else?

Comment: tried on four data frames with 10000 rows each and 30 columns, it will generate a new df with 10000 rows and 12 columns, and only values from df1. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @DracoMalfago, could you check it again?

Comment: Nice one, cleaner with the `n` solution and will work in general. Thanks!

Comment: lol guru!? That's just too much of responsibility! :) Let me see though, if I could help out.

Comment: @MaxU I hope the edits look okay :) Test it out at your end too! The added NumPy solution has hard-coded numbers corresponding to sample sizes, which could be generalized if needed.

Comment: @Divakar, that looks perfect, thank you! But i was hoping that you will add your own answer....

Comment: But feel free to edit those parts with the parameters `n`, etc. as OP might be looking to extend the actual case with many rows and columns.

Comment: @Divakar, i've substituted literals with variables in your answer, so OP might use it with DFs of different shape. I hope the edit looks OK for you?

Comment: Yup, looks perfect to me! Just need to ping OP ;)

Comment: @DracoMalfago, please check a brand new solution from Divakar - it's more elegant and should be much faster compared to mine

Comment: @MaxU Divakar, nice guys, the first solution with 4 dfs and 30x10000 (col x rows) takes about 0.56 seconds and the latter one 0.40 seconds (mean of 100 runs) so the numpy solution is faster. And the numpy solution is faster because pandas is built up on numpy?

Comment: @DracoMalfago, well, it depends... Sometimes pandas is faster because some method are optimized and are using other algorithms, sometimes NumPy approach is faster. But for this particular case in can't be done with pure pandas methods, because you want to destroy columns consistency (pandas was designed to keep the columns consistency)

Comment: @DracoMalfago In this case, NumPy is winning mainly being a vectorized solution. There's no hard and fast rule whether a NumPy or pandas would be faster over other. But from my few weeks of pandas experience, here's a very generic observation - If you are working with regular sized (without Nulls/NaNs) numeric data, do consider NumPy.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this?

```
import random
import numpy as np

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
n = np.sum(len(df.columns) for df in dfs)
pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).iloc[:, random.sample(range(n), n)]

Out[130]: 
  col1 col3 col1 col2 col1 col1 col2 col2 col3 col3 col3 col2
0  4_1  4_3  1_1  4_2  2_1  3_1  1_2  3_2  1_3  3_3  2_3  2_2
```

Or, if only the df's should be shuffled, you can do:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
random.shuffle(dfs)
pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

Out[133]: 
  col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3
0  4_1  4_2  4_3  2_1  2_2  2_3  1_1  1_2  1_3  3_1  3_2  3_3
```

Comment: More pythonic yes, the second solution what was I was after, however, this is similar to my solution, but it will only applies for one row. What If I have 1000 rows and want every single row to be suffled? Updated question. (my solution wasn't right after all)

Comment: Can you post a multi-row example because I couldn't understand what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer it is easier and it works for every df dimension

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4])
df = df.sample(frac=1)
```

the sample gives you a random sample of the df. If you ask for the complete df. It will randomize the columns