# Save a csr_matrix and a numpy array in one file

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to save a large sparse csr_matrix and a numpy array to be able to read them back later.  Let X be the sparse csr_matrix and Y be the number array.

Currently I take the following slightly insane route.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np
def save_sparse_csr(filename,array):
    np.savez(filename,data = array.data ,indices=array.indices,
             indptr =array.indptr, shape=array.shape )

def load_sparse_csr(filename):
    loader = np.load(filename)
    return csr_matrix((  loader['data'], loader['indices'], loader['indptr']),
                         shape = loader['shape'])

save_sparse_csr("file1", X)
np.save("file2", Y)
```

Then when I want to read them in it is:

```
X = load_sparse_csr("file1.npz")
Y = np.load("file2.npy")
```

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to save a csr_matrix than this?
2. Can I save both X and Y to the same file somehow? I seems crazy to have to make two files for this.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I think scipy's loadmat supports structured arrays and as such different variable could be saved as fields : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

Comment: i would try to save it as [PyTables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129429/storing-numpy-sparse-matrix-in-hdf5-pytables)

Comment: @Divakar, could you please take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506360/randomly-concat-data-frames-by-row) if you will have some time? I'm pretty sure you will find more elegant numpy solution...

Comment: `loadmat` handles sparse matrices - in a MATLAB compatible format.  I don't think it uses `numpy` structured arrays for this.

Answer (score 0):

So you are saving the 3 array attributes of the `csr` along with its shape.  And that is sufficient to recreate the array, right?

What's wrong with that?  Even if you find a function that saves the `csr` for you, I bet it is doing the same thing - saving those same arrays.

The normal way in Python to save a class is to `pickle` it.  But the class has to create the appropriate pickle method.  `numpy` does that (essentially its `save` function).  But as far as I know `scipy.sparse` has not provided that.

Since `scipy.sparse` has its roots in the MATLAB sparse code (and C/Fortran code developed for linear algebra problems), it can load/save using the `loadmat/savemat` functions.  I'd have to double check but I think the work with `csc` the default MATLAB sparse format.

There are one or two other `sparse.io` modules than handle sparse, but I have worked with those.  There formats for sharing sparse arrays among different packages working with the same problems (for example PDEs or finite element).  More than likely those formats will use a `coo` compatible layout (data, rows, cols), either as 3 arrays, a csv of 3 columns, or 2d array.

Mentioning `coo` format raises another possibility.  Make a structure array with `data, row, col` fields, and use `np.save` or even `np.savetxt`.  I don't think it's any faster or cleaner than `csr` direct.  But it does put all the data in one array (but `shape` might still need a separate entry).

You might also be able to pickle the `dok` format, since it is a `dict` subclass.

Comment: Can I put it all in one file easily? That is X and Y?

Comment: `np.save` puts just one array in a file.  `np.savez` saves multiple arrays (one per file in the archive), just as you are doing with the 3 attributes of `X`.  You could include `Y` in that collection.  There's no requirement that the arrays match in shape or type.  Your `indptr` does not match the `indices` in shape.