# Row-wise concat with sample 2 dataframes

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I've got 2 dataframes,

```
df1
      col1    col2   col3
    0  ABC  XYZ123  RA100
    1  DEF  YHG753  RA200
    2  ABC  XYZ123  RA100
    3  DEF  YHG753  RA200
    4  ABC  XYZ123  RA100
    5  DEF  YHG753  RA200

df2
      col5 col6
    0  TU1  DUM1
    1  TU2  DUM2
    2  TU3  DUM3
```

I'm trying to **concat each row of `df1` with a randomly selected row from `df2`**.

I've been trying with `pd.concat(frames, axis=1)`, but `concat` wont work for me as `shape` of the dataframes are not matching. So I'm wondering whether there's a better way to do to do this rather than increasing the rows of `df2` to match it with that of `df1`, then do `concat`.

Reference:
[Randomly concat data frames by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506360/randomly-concat-data-frames-by-row)

Expected sample output:

```
  col1    col2   col3  col5 col6 
0  ABC  XYZ123  RA100  TU3  DUM3
1  DEF  YHG753  RA200  TU1  DUM1
2  ABC  XYZ123  RA100  TU2  DUM2
3  DEF  YHG753  RA200  TU2  DUM2
4  ABC  XYZ123  RA100  TU3  DUM3
5  DEF  YHG753  RA200  TU1  DUM1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is create helper column with random assign index value of `df2.index` and then use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
#for test
np.random.seed(2002)

df = (df1.assign(id=np.random.choice(df2.index, size=len(df1)))
         .join(df2, on='id')
         .drop('id', axis=1))
print (df)
  col1    col2   col3 col5  col6
0  ABC  XYZ123  RA100  TU2  DUM2
1  DEF  YHG753  RA200  TU3  DUM3
2  ABC  XYZ123  RA100  TU1  DUM1
3  DEF  YHG753  RA200  TU2  DUM2
4  ABC  XYZ123  RA100  TU1  DUM1
5  DEF  YHG753  RA200  TU1  DUM1
```

Another idea is merge by numpy array in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
np.random.seed(2002)

idx = np.random.choice(df2.index, size=len(df1))
         
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=idx, right_index=True).drop('key_0', axis=1)
print (df)
  col1    col2   col3 col5  col6
0  ABC  XYZ123  RA100  TU2  DUM2
3  DEF  YHG753  RA200  TU2  DUM2
1  DEF  YHG753  RA200  TU3  DUM3
2  ABC  XYZ123  RA100  TU1  DUM1
4  ABC  XYZ123  RA100  TU1  DUM1
5  DEF  YHG753  RA200  TU1  DUM1
```